# Modelling this triangular prism pointy shape with good topology

Tags: modeling, topology

To learn and practice blender I try to model food. My current model has a triangular prism base shape with pointy ends on it.

Please show me another way of modelling this shape with those pointy ends, but with good topology (no tris on the surface).

[image]

this is what recently i came up with. and quite satisfied for now.

[image]

Comment: That topology should be fine, could you expand more on what your trying to do?

Comment: @FrosticWolf i thought that way too. but, if we check near those three conic points, they don't really look like conical much. pardon my english.
those ends have kind of obvious steps on them. unlike smooth cones.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot spot any triangle faces. The topology looks fine.

Comment: The topology looks great .. maybe 1 more edge loop around the perimeter for flexibility at the corners? Or if you're feeling extravagant , 1 level of subdiv applied, and continue modeling the irregularities?

Comment: i've came up with different way of modelling the shape. going to edit the post to show you.